# wordpress doing register but login with the same credentials not working

Tags: ajax, wordpress, password-protection

I have created a register form in wordpress and doing register in ajax.
The form is like this

```
<form id="user-register-form" method="" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="full-column-width">
            <div class="half-column-width">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" id="firstname" required="" aria-required="true">
            </div>
            <div class="half-column-width">
                <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastname" required="" aria-required="true">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-column-width">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" id="email" required="" aria-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="full-column-width">
            <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" required="" aria-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="full-column-width">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required="" aria-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="full-column-width">
            <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="user_get_register" value="Register">
        </div>
    </form>
```

in the functions file I have made my function like this

```
function user_register() {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
     parse_str($data, $arr);
    $userdata = array (
        'user_login' => $arr['email'],
        'firstname' => $arr['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $arr['lastname'],
        'email' => $arr['email'],
        'phone' => $arr['phone'],
        'password' => $arr['password'],
        );
    //check username exists
    if( username_exists( $arr['email'] ) ) {
        echo 'username exists';
    } 
    else {
        $id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
        if( !is_wp_error( $id )) {
            wp_set_current_user($id);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($id);
            echo 'user created';
        }
    }
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_user_register', 'user_register');
```

It is doing register the user with its details but when I am doing the same details for login from the wordpress admin login its not working. I have checked the database. The values are there. Everytime when I am doing login to the dashboard it is showing

```
ERROR: The password you entered for the username test@name.com is incorrect.
```

Can someone tell me why this error? and how to solve this?

Comment: Check CSS rules in the inputs. Maybe they have text-transform or something.

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake in user data, change password to `user_pass`

```
$userdata = array (
    'user_login' => $arr['email'],
    'firstname' => $arr['firstname'],
    'lastname' => $arr['lastname'],
    //'email' => $arr['email'], ---- cant store this with this function
    //'phone' => $arr['phone'], --- cant store this with this function
    'user_pass' => $arr['password'],
    );
```

Also you are passing in keys that dont exist for wp_insert_user(), you need to save these as usermeta =

```
update_user_meta( $id, '_telephone', '555-555' );
```